# Invalid Qualifier when checking for a specific character in visual basic

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Hi i am trying to check for a specific character in visual vba but i encountered the "INVALID QUALIFIER" error when i run my code.

This is my code:

```
 For i = LBound(rtv) To UBound(rtv) - 1
        If rtv(i).Contains(":") Then
            Value = Split(rtv(i), ":")
            rtv(i) = Chr(34) & Value(0) & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & Value(1) & Chr(34) & ";"

        Else
            rtv(i) = Chr(34) & rtv(i) & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & Chr(34)

       ' rtv(i) = Chr(34) & rtv(i) & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ";"
    Next i
```

The error lies in the IF statement condition but i have no idea what i am doing wrong here. Any help ?

Comment: `rtv` is an array and doesn't accept a `.Contains` function

Comment: `rtv(i).Contains(":")` will not work in VBA. Use `InStr` instead

Comment: what exactly is your code doing. it looks like a misguided code for referencing worksheet cells ... where does the value of `rtv` come from?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, `rtv(i).Contains()` won't work. Arrays don't have functions or properties that you can use this way.

Use this instead:

```
If InStr(rtv(i),":") > 0 Then
```